# Can downstream device connect using SAS token signed by Shared Access policy?

Tags: azure, azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-edge

While using Azure IoT Edge as a transparent gateway, can downstream devices authenticate using SAS tokens using the Shared Access Policy keys? (device, iothubowner etc?). We have being able to successfully connect using SAS tokens signed by the device primary keys, but trying to do so with Shared Access Policy keys doesn't seem to work.

Note: The devices are using MQTT

Comment: Can you provide any more information about how you're doing the signing? For example, are you using one of the IoT Hub device SDKs? Could you also share why you want to use the Shared Access Policy keys instead of the device keys?

Comment: We were trying to avoid having to deal with one key per device while creating SAS tokens. The leaf devices use a java paho client to connect to Azure IoT Hub with Edge set up as a transparent gateway. (leaf device to edge communication is over MQTT, which currently just supports SAS tokens)

We used the bash script mentioned in this document, (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/eventhub/generate-sas-token#bash)

Is it supported? The uri passed to generate the token is '{iothub}/devices/{deviceid}' and skn=device. Are we missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that script (which is an eventhub script) creates the right SAS tokens for IoT Hub.   The easiest way to do it is to do it from the Azure Cloud CLI  (in the azure portal, click on the ">_" button up in the top nav bar..  then you can run this command:

az iot hub generate-sas-token -n [your iothub name] --policy device --key-type primary --duration [duration in seconds you want the token to be valid]

Try using that SAS token.  I tested this tonight with the python paho.mqtt client and it worked fine.  It connected to IoT Edge and successfully sent messages to both a module and IoT Hub.

Comment: as an aside, if the command above doesn’t work in the cloud CLI, you may have to run this command to install the iot hub extension to the base azure cli<br>

az extension add --name azure-cli-iot-ext

Comment: Thanks Steve. To add to the above what worked for us was to use the registryRead policy key to scope it to the device

az iot hub generate-sas-token -d [deviceid] -n [your iothub name] --policy registryRead --key-type primary --duration [duration in seconds you want the token to be valid]

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this should work if the device is not a child device of the Edge Device in IoTHub. Look at these links to find out more about how to add devices as a child device of an Edge Device https://aka.ms/exofdocs and https://aka.ms/iot-edge-offline.

This is because, if the leaf device is a child device, EdgeHub will try to authenticate it locally, and for that it only uses the device’s key.

If the leaf device is not a child device of the Edge Device, then you should be able to connect to the EdgeHub using the device/iothub scoped key, since then the EdgeHub will authenticate the device with IoTHub. Note that the connection string should be of the format – 
HostName=.azure-devices.net;DeviceId=;SharedAccessKeyName=;SharedAccessKey=;GatewayHostName=

Comment: Hi Varun, the downstream leaf devices aren't using Azure SDKs. They connect and send messages to the Edge using a Java PAHO client. Could that be the cause of the issue?  Do we need to set the upstream protocol from Edge to IoT Hub to MQTT as well for this to work? The logs show the following error :

'Error opening IoTHub connection for device
Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Client.Exceptions.UnauthorizedException: Put token failed. status-code: 401, status-description: The specified SAS token has invalid signature. It does not match either the primary or secondary key'

Comment: We used the bash script mentioned in this document, to generate the token (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/eventhub/generate-sas-token#bash)